# built in command line pager/viewer like less? Without busybox or root access

Tags: shell, busybox

Sometimes i investigate foreign phones, where i can't root or install any Apps.

But i want to examine the filesystem via adb shell, and view some text-files. Like i usually do with a *nix-shell: with the `less` or the `more` command.

Both are absent in the shell, that i can access with `adb shell`.

My workaround until now is using the linux tool `screen` in conjunction with the adb-shell-command `cat`. (`C-a Esc` to scroll, '`/`' to search, `Esc Esc` to quit Copy-mode)

Comment: Can you provide more specifics of what your question is? Are you wanting to know if there is a way to use something like less or more in an Android Terminal Emulator or when using ADB on a computer? when running adb commands I would think that you would be able to pipe them to less, more or grep. To sue them from a Terminal Emulator I am pretty sure that you have to have root and busybox. Also, what kind of device are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Ok it was less obvious then i thought, i know i can run `adb shell cat /path/to/my/file | less` but i like to do `adb shell` ones, and then something like `less /path/to/my/file`.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is a bit old. But I run into exactly the same problem and would like to share my solutions.

## 1st solution

Check if **toybox** is installed. If you are lucky, `ls | toybox more` may work.

## 2nd solution

However, I am not satisfied with the first solution, since **more** does not support going backwards. It turns out that **vim** is installed. In this case, you can run `ls | vim -`.

## 3rd solution

If you use **emacs**, calling **adb shell** in **shell** or **eshell** solves the problem. This is more or less the same as your **screen** workaround.

Comment: I just want to add that toybox was shipped with Android starting with Lollipop.